# How to translate "var a = collection?.First()?.somePropA ?? new A();"

Tags: c#, nullable, null-coalescing

What is the purpose of single question mark on the right side of assignment in expression with null-coalescing operator? Example:

```
var a = collection?.First()?.somePropA ?? new A();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The single quotation mark (`?.`) is newly added in C# 6.0 and represents a `null` check.

So, for example, the following code is the same;

```
var foo = bar?.bar2;
```

Or

```
var foo = null;
if (bar != null)
    foo = bar.bar2;
else
    foo = null;
```

However, both can still return `null`. Therefore one can use the `??` check to assign a value if the result indeed is `null`.

That being said, one can write the following code;

```
var foo = bar?.bar2 ?? new Bar2();
```

which is basically the same as

```
var foo = null;
if (bar != null)
    foo = bar.bar2;
else
    foo = new Bar2();
```

Using `?.` multiple times can really shorten your code. Consider, for example, the following line;

```
var foo = bar?.bar2?.bar3?.bar4?.bar5 ?? new Bar5();
```

this is syntactic sugar for

```
var foo = null;
if (bar != null)
{
    if (bar.bar2 != null)
    {
        if (bar.bar2.bar3 != null)
        {
            if (bar.bar2.bar3.bar4 != null)
            {
                if (bar.bar2.bar3.bar4.bar5 != null)
                    foo = bar.bar2.bar3.bar4.bar5;
                else
                    foo = new Bar5();
            }
            else
                foo = new Bar5();
        }
        else
            foo = new Bar5();
    }
    else
        foo = new Bar5();
}
else
    foo = new Bar5();
```

Of course, there are already way better ways to write the above (for example, by initializing `foo = new Bar5()` before doing all the checks), but for clarity I kept it this way.

Answer (score 3):

`?.` is a new operator that helps a developer to omit excessive checks for null.

You can read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx

Answer (score 2):

`collection.First()` takes the first item from the collection. If that is not `null` it will call `somePropA`. If it is `null` (here comes the purpose of this operator), it will return `null`: it is just a smart way to do a null check. It is called the [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx).

That single character prevents the need for checking each and every property or return value for `null`.

Another way to write this:

```
var a = ( collection != null && collection.First() != null
          ? collection.First().somePropA : null
        ) ?? new A();
```

Or:

```
A a;

if (collection != null && collection.First() != null)
{
    a = collection.First().somePropA;
}
else
{
    a = null;
}

if (a == null)
{
    a = new A();
}
```

Comment: There is one reason the ?. operator is even better than the rewrite with IFs in your answer - every part is evaluated only once (see calling First() twice in your code?).
That's why it is usefull for firing events without checking for the delegate being null: someEvent?.Invoke();